# Linq2DB adding unnecessary statements to query

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq2db

I am trying to generate a query that gets the number of entries with dates that occur within each given month.  The SQL form of the query I wish to generate goes like this:

```
SELECT
DatePart(Year, [t1].[StartTime]) as Year,
DatePart(Month, [t1].[StartTime]) as Month,
Count(*) as 'Visits',
Sum([t1].[PageCount]) as 'Total Pageviews'
FROM
[MyDatabase] [t1]
GROUP BY
DatePart(Year, [t1].[StartTime]),
DatePart(Month, [t1].[StartTime])
```

I tried the following Linq2DB code:

```
var query = from table in dataContext.MyDataContext(tablePath)
group table by new { table.StartTime.Year, table.StartTime.Month} into grp
select new { Month = grp.Key.Month, Year = grp.Key.Year,
TotalVisitors =   grp.Count(), 
TotalPageviews = grp.Sum(table2 => table2.PageCount) };
```

but the SQL query being generated by this is

```
--  SqlServer.2008  --
SELECT
[t1].[StartTime],
Count(*) as [c1],
Sum([t1].[PageCount]) as [c2]
FROM
[MyDatabase] [t1]
GROUP BY
DatePart(Year, [t1].[StartTime]),
DatePart(Month, [t1].[StartTime]),
[t1].[StartTime]
```

Why is [t1].[StartTime] rather than the month or year?  And why is it grouping by that extra [t1].[StartTime] at the end?  How do I generate the SQL query I have above using Linq2DB?

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following workaround with **Sql.AsSql** function. We are trying to fix this longstanding issue.

```
var query = from table in dataContext.MyDataContext(tablePath)
group table by new { Sql.AsSql(table.StartTime.Year), Sql.AsSql(table.StartTime.Month)} into grp
select new { Month = Sql.AsSql(grp.Key.Month), Year = Sql.AsSql(grp.Key.Year),
TotalVisitors =   grp.Count(), 
TotalPageviews = grp.Sum(table2 => table2.PageCount) };
```